join salesforce flow record collections
I am creating separate record collections using getRecords element. Each has a common unique key. Is there a way to 'join' these record collections into a single collection ? I would like to display the result in a data table on a screen element.

One solution for this is the UnofficialSF.com Collections Processor for Flow, specifically Join Collections
This is a superb installable component that can perform all sorts of collections operations without recourse to messy Flow loops
From the doc
Join Collections

Takes two collections (of the same type, please!) and returns their union as a single collection.
Inputs
List inputCollection1;
List inputCollection2;
Outputs
List outputCollection;

After installing the package and its prerequisites, add an Apex action to your flow and provide the two collections to be joined; the output of the Apex action is the joined collection

Thanks for the info. Any thoughts if Salesforce will provide the same without apex ?

over time, SFDC has been rolling out into native Flow features that UnofficialSf.com has as apex actions; follow SFDC release notes and dreamforce sessions to gain insight. Note that to you, the flow user, it is just an apex action and once the package is installed, you need not think about it again; just use it as any other flow component

Thanks again. Only constraint is our security team takes @ a year to approve downloading anything so we usually have to build it. The challenges of working for a large regulated firm.

too bad --- UNofficalSf.com is so useful; it wouldn't be hard to write a join collections apex action
